# Relation between Ecmascript and the window object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I know that the window object is what the current browser has to offer as far as functionality is concerned.

But how is Ecmascript related to this? How is it included in the browser, and how do I know which browser that loads which version of ecmascript?

For example, [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/) is some Ecmascript 5 object properties. How am I supposed to know if it's supported in the current browser instance?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/ is a good site for being able to tell which browsers support which HTML5/CSS3 behaviours.

Comment: @jbabey Thanks but this doesn't necessarily have to do with anything related to HTML5 and/or css3. Version 5 of Ecmascript was just an example.

Comment: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 0):

You can always resort to feature testing e.g.

```
var preventExtensionSupport = !!Object.preventExtensions;
var ownPropertyDescriptorSupport = !!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor
```

Comment: And how is ecmascript loaded in to the browser?